# JDBC driver not load when launch Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I try to launch alfresco in my local post, but i still getting this error:

> Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource'

So i tried to add `h2database` dependency to my `pom.xml`; but i still getting the same error.
Is there anyone who got this error.
any idea to how resolve this problem.

Comment: `org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource` is not a JDBC driver. The driver class name is `org.h2.Driver` for H2

Comment: Ok, so how i can resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you actually using H2? Is this all started from Eclipse using new SDK? How are you starting this Alfresco?

Comment: I tried to start the Alfresco from the project repository, and from eclipse and i have the same result. I use the sdk 3.3